# Serialize and deserialize perl DBI connection object

Tags: perl, dbi, storable

I need serialize one array with DBI connection objects to shared with others process using shared memory. But deserialize not working.

use storable qw/freeze thaw/;

```
my @connections;

for(my $c = 0;$c < 5;$c++) {
  my $conn = DBI->connect($dsn,$user,$password,{'AutoCommit' => 1, 'RaiseError' => 1, 'PrintError' => 0});
  push(@connections,$conn);
}

my $shm = freeze(@connections);
my $obj = thaw($shm);
```

Return error:
Global symbol

> "$drh" requires explicit package name (did you forget to declare "my
>   $drh"?) at (eval 33) line 6.

Comment: That sounds like a terrible idea. Also, where's the rest of your code?

Comment: My code have 10 packages (class). My application need optimized number connections with database. My application begin with one connection with database, it did 100 forks sharing connections. If one child open connection, it share the connection with parent and other process. I did same semaphores to control access to connections

Comment: Could I send to you?

Comment: This sounds like an elaborate attempt at connection pooling.

Answer (score 12):

You cannot serialize a database handle/connection since it consists of user space data not reachable by Storable (i.e. outside Perl and inside the database library and maybe also in the TLS library) and also kernel data like file descriptors.

Comment: So as I share connections open after the fork?

Comment: @evertongava: fork is a system call which clones the whole processes. This includes all user space and all kernel data. So it will work first. But it might stop working if you use the same database handle after the fork from multiple processes because there might be a state involved which gets not shared between these processes. This might be different between database drivers but it is definitely true if the database connection is done with TLS.

Comment: The idea is to have an application that could have 10-100 connections with database. I start one semget with 100 semaphores but only one connection. As demand increases, it open another connections and use another semaphores. If demand decrease and connections are idle for one minute, they are closed. This system controls on-board computers of 300,000 vehicles are 3,000 messages per minute. But there are times of the day It need more resources and times It less resources. Each vehicle has an intelligent agent (process) that track it for a period. It is a legacy system made in perl.

Comment: @evertongava: it does not matter what kind of application you have: serialization of database handle will still not work. If you want to know how to design the application with that limitation in mind please ask a different question with more details about the application and its current design.